# Twitter bootstrap typeahead to autocomplete on continuing to enter on same input form

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap 2.3.2 , Here is the html snippet to use typeahead feature

```
<input id="shareMessage" type="text" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="2" data-source='["Apple","Ball","Cat","Doll"]' />
```

Typeahead works and suggests auto-completion during the first suggestion in the input box , but after i continue typing in the same input box it doesnt make anyother suggestion, why is it that it works only for the first suggestion and doesnt work as i continue entering data in the same text box ?? How to resolve this ??